# Why can't this matrix have a right inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with m > n. Why can't $A$ have a right inverse.

We want $AB = I_m$, why is this impossible if $m > n$?

Answer (score 3):

Think about $A$ as the linear transformation that it represents: $T:\mathbf{R}^n\to \mathbf{R}^m$. We know that the number of columns corresponds to the dimension of the domain, while the number of rows corresponds to the dimension of the codomain. We know, then, that $m>n$. So, we know that $T$ can not be surjective. Existence of a right inverse is equivalent to surjectivity. Therefore, $T$ has no right inverse. Similarly, $A$ has no right inverse.

Answer (score 1):

because the rank of $A$ is no larger than $n$

Which means that $AB$ has rank no larger than $n.$ But $ n < m$

Comment: Pardon me, but what does rank say here? (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You can see $A$ as a linear map $A:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$. The existence of a right inverse is equivalent to $A$ being onto.

But since $\mathbb R^n$ is $n$-dimensional, the range of $A$ has dimension at most $n$. From $n<m$, we get that $A$ cannot be onto, and so it cannot have a right inverse.