# Why can't rectangular matrices have a two sided inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I am following Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra course ([link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/index.htm)).

In lecture 33, he mentions that a rectangular matrix can’t have a two-sided inverse because either that matrix or its transpose has a nonzero null space. I know the condition for the null space for a square matrix to be invertible (null space must contain only the zero vector). However, I am not able to figure out how the null space comes in when we are talking about left and right inverses.

Referring to the example given in the course lecture: We take an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with $m>n$. $A$ has full column rank. We can compute the left inverse as $A_{left}^{-1} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ using the invertibility of $A^TA$. He mentions that the right inverse will not exist. I think this has to do something with $N(A^T)$ being nontrivial, but I am not able to figure out the exact relation.

Could someone please explain the relation between invertibility for rectangular matrices and its relation between the two null spaces?

Comment: If $xA=0$ and $AB=I$ then $xAB=(xA)B=0B=0$ but also $xAB=x(AB)=xI=x$, contradiction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'd say that is actually an answer rather than a comment!

Comment: @math, chances are the question is a duplicate. But feel free to write it up as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, the closest question I found to mine was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225575/why-cant-this-matrix-have-a-right-inverse. However, it asks only about the right inverse and does not have any mention of the relation with null spaces, so I thought  of asking a new question

Comment: If a matrix has a two sided inverse then it induces a linear trasformation between vectorspaces $\mathbb R^a\to  \mathbb R^b$ that is an isomorphisms, i.e. that has a two sided inverse. Conclude that $a=b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $=0$ and $=$ then $=()=0=0$ but also $=()==$